# Add category slug in post page

Tags: content-management-system, blogs, octobercms, slug

I am beginner in october cms and using rainlab blog plugin for my personal blog.
I want to display category slug in the url of blog post page, how can i achieve that?

i.e example.com/{category_slug}/{blog_post_slug}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be `example.com/:category?/:slug?`

Unless you skip the component all together there is no way around that. The Blog component for a post is just looking for the slug: `:slug`. I don't think you really have to worry about people changing the category in my opinion. Your post list page should have the url `example.com/category/post` for its link. Why would a user change the category?

[image]

If you really care here is a way around that. **Don't use the blog post component**. Make your own plugin or use CMS Pages. The code will vary slightly and in this example I will use CMS Page code cause it is 'ad hoc' and quicker.

```
use Rainlab\Blog\Models\Post;
function onStart() {
    $category = $this->param('category');
    $slug = $this->param('slug');
    $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
            $query->where('slug', $category);
        })->get();
    $this['post'] = $posts->where('slug', $slug)->first();
}
```

Comment: That worked but then even if i'm writing anything in the category part it is loading blog page.

example.com/abc/blog-slug
example.com/blog-category/blog-slug

both returns the same blog page which is not right i think.

Comment: That should get me started. Thank you